# How to make a dependency on a command line parameter

Tags: scons

I have a command line variable (text string) which I inject into a file (the target file) using a builder.  The question is, how to I trigger the building of the target file when the value of the the command line string changes?

One option might be to write the string to a text file, but I'd need to write that text file every time I build.  Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: How do you inject it into the file? Is the string ever present on a command line?

Comment: I inject it with python code (open->modify->write).  Yes, the string is present on the command line.

Comment: Can you  pastebin your logic for modifying this file? That will help a lot in determining if there's a simpler way to resolve your query.

Comment: The logic is pretty complex, basically I open the source, generate a new file based on it, and then write it out to a new file. I'm happy with @dirkbaechle's answer below for this issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this really qualifies as "cleaner" way, but you can create a `Value` node:

```
mynode = env.Value(my_var_string)
```

and then use the `Depends()` method to let your target depend on this Value node:

```
env.Depends(final_target, mynode)
```

Please check the MAN page ( http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html ) for a complete description of the `Value` method.

Comment: Awesome...that's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!